# 知らない間にコメントが削除されているのはなぜですか？

Tags: サポート, コメント, モデレーション

下記の質問において私のコメントが削除されています。
[UI部品が表示されたりされなかったりします。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14785/)

これが、本人に通知なく理由の説明なく秘密裏に行われているのは問題だと考えます。その後同様の趣旨のコメントが別人により行われ解決への進展を見せてしまっています。

どのような理由かわからないですが、この件は「個人の技術的貢献への敬意」を欠いていると思います。

削除理由を明らかにし私のコメントを復旧して欲しいです。そして何よりコメントのモデレーションにおける透明性を高めてほしいです。それが、モデーレーター・モデレーションの正当性の評価につながると考えるからです。

Comment: [スパムまたは不快として通報するとどうなりますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: [モデレーションでコメントの削除をする際は技術的な内容を残してほしい](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1917/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AF%E6%8A%80%E8%A1%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)

Comment: [このサイトでは、表現は自由です。が、標準語と丁寧語を推奨します。
争い、紛争を避けるための注意事項があります。表現についての投票は個人の判断に委ねられます。多くの人が気分を害す表現での、揉め事・喧嘩・紛争・炎上のおそれのある場合、速やかに通報してください。予告なしに該当の質問、回答またはコメントが編集、削除、クローズ、凍結され、その件について誰も責任を負うことはありません。](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1971/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E7%B4%B9%E4%BB%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F-%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AE%E3%83%84%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

そのコメントはモデレーターによって手動で削除されたわけではありません。

このサイトでは一定数の通報があると、その投稿が自動的に削除されることがあります。コメントの場合、現在は以下の基準で処理されています。

> Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically. The number of flags needed is based on the comment's score. It currently takes "`3 + (Score / 3)`" flags to delete a comment.
>   <sub>--- [How do comments work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/286934) より引用</sub>

ご指摘のコメントはスコアが 0 でしたので、3人のユーザーから通報された時点で自動削除されました。

---

> 1. コメントが削除されたことが投稿者本人に知らされない事。モデレーターが削除した際はメンションを残さない限り通知されない事は教えてもらっている。自動削除についてもそ‌​うなのか？

はい。モデレーターが削除しようと、システムで自動削除しようと、コメントが削除されたという通知は行われません。これは質問や回答でも同じです。

> 2. 本件の削除理由が分からない。

これは単純に伝えることを忘れていました。3件の通報全てが「失礼または不快」、英語版で言うところの「rude or offensive」として通報されています。

> 理由が不明かつ本人に告知なく行われることが問題だと俺は思う。

前回の質問にせよ今回の質問にせよ、「なぜ削除したのか。せめて技術的な内容を残してほしい」ということが主軸にあると感じられました。ここで削除告知について論じた場合、仮に技術的な内容がなければ「理由が不明かつ本人に告知なく」削除されてもいいのか、という話になってしまいます。

故に、「モデレーターが削除する際にはコメントを残すべき」「自動削除される際に通知してほしい」といった問題については、別投稿にされた方が議論がしやすいかと思います。いかがでしょうか。

Comment: 詳しい説明をありがとう。削除の経緯が理解できた。モデレーターが無言で削除した事を疑って悪かった。だがこの質問（問題）の二つの要点は不明のままだ

Comment: 二つの要点とは、1. コメントが削除されたことが投稿者本人に知らされない事。モデレーターが削除した際はメンションを残さない限り通知されない事は教えてもらっている。自動削除についてもそうなのか？ 2. 本件の削除理由が分からない。通報の際は理由を選択できる。ならば通報者以外の誰か（モデレーターや信頼度の高いユーザーということだが）はその理由を知っていると思うのだがこの回答でモデレーターであるあなたが理由を明かさないのはモデレーターでも知り得ないのか、自動削除の理由をメタで尋ねても答えない方針であるのかどちらかなのか？/理由が不明かつ本人に告知なく行われることが問題だと俺は思う。それはこの質問（http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1917/）をしたときと一貫して変わらない

Comment: @user10678 ご指摘の内容について回答に追記しました

Comment: 追加の回答ありがとう。今回の件ではモデレーターの無言削除と通報による自動削除の判別は投稿者本人にはできないということも分かった。/ 最後に挙げられた二つの問題の議論を始める気はない。モデレーターがコメントを残すかどうかはモデレーターが判断することだ。その判断基準の助けになる情報が欲しいなら自身で皆に問えばいい。俺は既に要望は伝えている。そしてあなたがたはコメントを残してくれている。他の人間がどう思っているか知って判断基準に加えるのはモデレーター自身だから俺が議論を始めたりはしない。自動削除の際に本人に通知しろという機能要望は単品では用を成さないので意味がない。モデレーションが秘密裏に行われることに反対していることを考えればそれがわかると思う。

Comment: @user10678 あなたがモデレーションが秘密裏に行われていることに反対していることは前回の質問で知っていたので、[コメント](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1977?noredirect=1#comment1210_1978)で繰り返し主張されるからには（議論したいなどの）理由があるのかと思った次第です。が、勘違いだったようで、失礼いたしました。