# 『知らない間にコメントが削除されている』の質問が削除されている

Tags: バグ, 仕様

[『知らない間にコメントが削除されている』](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1977/)の質問が削除されているにもかかわらず、
[FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1484/)内にはリンクが残ったままです。

Answer (score 2):

[「スコアがマイナスの質問・回答は、投稿者のアカウント削除と同時に削除される」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2283/)、という基準に従って自動で削除されてしまったようです。

削除の取り消しに投票しておきました。
マイナス票が付いているのにも理由はあるでしょうから、他に取り消し票が集るかどうか分かりませんが。

（コミュニティWikiにして、穏当な表現に編集しなおすべきなのかも。よく分かりません。）