# ユーザ登録を解除した者による質問は Community♦ に削除されるのか

Tags: サポート

さすがに質問者が自身のユーザ登録を解除しただけで質問が削除される事はないだろうと思っています。
もう少し厳しい条件があると思うのですが、[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28528/)が削除された理由が他に見当たらないので、この辺のルールなどあれば知りたいです。

ヘルプセンターの[「私の質問がCommunityユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)には該当する物が無かったです。
(それとも、上記の質問は質問者が削除したのでしょうか。その後に質問者のユーザ登録が無くなったので Community♦ が削除した扱いになっているとか？)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スコアがマイナスの質問・回答は、投稿者のアカウント削除と同時に削除されます。

参考 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/286934

> ### How can a post be deleted?
>
> #### By the system:
>
> 10. The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.

ご指摘の質問、それから先ほど[別の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2281/8000)で言及されていた質問、どちらもスコアが-1なので、この基準に基づいて削除されたようですね。

Comment: ちょっと予想外の基準でしたが、本家で運用されているという事は投稿が増えると必要になる事なのかも知れないですね。回答ありがとうございます。